# Looking for a friendly eLogBook for laboratory

Tags: web-apps, web-services, collaboration, web-server, log-analysis

We are a lab team and we got the task to summarize all our work, the have explain me what a logbook is, a they ask me for configure one. Searching on internet I have found this post: [Simple laboratory logbook functionality for a small research group, Python or otherwise](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/71986/simple-laboratory-logbook-functionality-for-a-small-research-group-python-or-ot/81990#81990)*  but that doesn't have a clear response, I have asked in the post and rewrote the question.

It needs to be friendly, to say the group "install it" and start to write.
If I can edit or write it, with Python, it will be very satisfactory for our work.